# Jquery post bootstrap form to dropwizard resource getting internal server error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dropwizard

This is the html code I have written

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load jQuery and the validate plugin -->
  </head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="datepicker.css">
  <body>       
    <h1>&nbsp</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <form id="addMaterial-form">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                <label for="materialCode">Material Code</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control " id="materialCode" placeholder="Enter Material Code" name="materialCode"/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                <label for="job">Description</label>
                <textarea class="form-control "  rows="5" id="description" placeholder="Enter Something" name="description"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                <label for="purchaseDate">Date Of Purchase</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control " id="purchaseDate" placeholder="Date of Purchase" name="purchaseDate"/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                <label for="stock">Stock</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control " id="stock" placeholder="Enter Stock" name="stock"/>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <button  type="submit" id="submitButton" class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-4 btn btn-default">Save</button>
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <span class="label label-danger col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4 " id="messageFromServer" ></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
      <script src="datepicker.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      // When the document is ready
      $(document).ready(function () {

      $('#purchaseDate').datepicker({
      format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
      todayHighlight:true,
      autoclose:true,
      endDate:'+0d'
      });

      });

      $('#addMaterial-form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      alert("gonna do");
      $.post('/insertMaterial', {"materialCode": "78","stock": "78","description": "fhfhgf","purchaseDate": "09/05/2013"} );

      event.preventDefault();
      });
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

The issue is whenever I click on submit I get an internal server error.The server error can be removed by changing post function to

```
      $.post('/insertMaterial', JSON.stringify({"materialCode": "78","stock": "78","description": "fhfhgf","purchaseDate": "09/05/2013"}) );
```

But at the server side I am unable to extract the form params using the above method I am getting only null values there.The server side is done in dropwizard framework

```
 @POST
public String addNewMaterial(@FormParam("materialCode") String materialCode, @FormParam("description") String description, @FormParam("purchaseDate") Date date, @FormParam("stock") double stock) {
    System.out.println("got " + materialCode + description + date + stock);
    return "OK";
}
```

Comment: have you tried doing /addNewMaterial instead of /insertMaterial?

Comment: I don't see any mapping from /insertMaterial to /addNewMaterial so I guess you are just calling the wrong endpoint

Comment: @JeremyC. I don't think the endpoint is wrong.Because I have tried using wget to send a request to /insertMaterial got the result exactly as I wanted.I believe the issue is with the Jquery post I have used.I dont have much idea in Jquery .